# How can we solve An entity with the same identity already exists in this EntitySet

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-4.0

```
public BusinessAccounting.ViewModel.Account.AccountViewModel AccountVM;    


public QBImportDataWizard()
{
    InitializeComponent();                
    dcBusinessAccountingContext.Load(dcBusinessAccountingContext.GetAccountsQuery());           
}

void oQB_RetrieveQBAccountsCompleted(object sender, QBAccountsServiceReference.RetrieveQBAccountsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (BusinessAccounting.QBAccountsServiceReference.QBAccounts acc in QBAccountlist)
    {
        AccountVM.CurrentAccount.Active = acc.Active;
        AccountVM.CurrentAccount.Hierarchy =null;
        AccountVM.CurrentAccount.HierarchyLevel = acc.Sublevel;
        AccountVM.CurrentAccount.CashFlowID = 3;
        AccountVM.CurrentAccount.OpeningBalance = null;
        AccountVM.CurrentAccount.OpeningBalanceDate = DateTime.Now;
        AccountVM.CurrentAccount.Category1099ID = null;
        AccountVM.CurrentAccount.Remarks ="";
        AccountVM.CurrentAccount.BankID = 0;//Here i am getting error.
    }
}
```

If I remove below line under `QBImportDataWizard()   dcBusinessAccountingContext.Load(dcBusinessAccountingContext.GetAccountsQuery());` then it is not giving any error. Let me know why?

Comment: Please format your code properly. And it only shows part of the story. Like, what is `Load` and when does the event fire?

Comment: You removed the line `dcBusinessAccountingContext.Accounts.Add(AccountVM.CurrentAccount);` which of course cause the exception. Your code keeps assigning values to the same object and adding the object to the context.